# result format (brackets) not removable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Beginner here: Please be kind. I want to show the result of a pandas DataFrame operation but I can't get rid of the brackets around the result. It's a small program that random picks an entry from a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

## enter choices
choicelist=[]
while True:
    entry =input('Enter an option (q to quit}')
    if entry =='q':
        break
    else:
        choicelist.append(entry)

## create df with weights
df= pd.DataFrame(choicelist, columns= ['Choice'])
df['Weight']= 1/len(df)
df['CumWeight']=df['Weight'].cumsum()

## generate random number
a= rd.random()
selection = df['Choice'][(a<=df.CumWeight) & (a>df.CumWeight-df.Weight)].values
print ('Random selected choice: '+selection)
## there is still a bracket around the result...
```

Eg, when entering 'a', 'b'

```
['Random selected choice: a']
```

But I want: 'Random selected choice: a'
PS: The data frame does not have the brackets:

```
df
Out[92]: 
  Choice  Weight  CumWeight
0      a     0.5        0.5
1      b     0.5        1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting your selection, `.values` returns a numpy array, even if there is only one item in the array. When you add the string `'Random selected choice: '` to the numpy array, it is still a numpy array, and so will print with brackets. To fix this, you could take the first item from selection only: `print ('Random selected choice: '+selection[0])`, and it should print as a normal string, without brackets.

Comment: Why didn't I think of it. I was close though.  trying to do selection[]